# Inkscape set inverse does not work?

Tags: inkscape, shapes

Inkscape uses clip -> and clip ->set inverse have the same result? Why is this happening?

[image]

Why does `set inverse` have the same effect as `set`? Shouldn't `set invers`e keep the opposite?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are clicking on since I don't read Chinese, can you change your interface Language to English please?.  I just tried *Object > Clip > Set Inverse (LPE)* and it works for me.  Looks like you are setting an ordinary clip to me.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it just now. I changed to English. Thanks

Comment: I've added an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use Inverse Clip (LPE) which is a Live Path Effect on a raster image.  Unfortunately, that command only works on vector objects, not raster images.

If you want, you can create an inverse shape manually to use as a kind of inverted clip instead.

Example. Here I made a rectangle bigger than the raster image I want to clip, and then I cut out another rectangle using *Path > Difference*. Then move that over the raster image and set it as a clip.

[image]

Comment: thank you. I just tried it and it works. I would like to ask how to change the position of the picture displayed in the interface. I use -> <-, but I cannot move my vision. This causes me to only view part of the picture, but not the other part?

Comment: @cyj - sorry I'm not sure what you mean. Some guesses: press 5 on your keyboard to view the whole page.  Move around the image  by clicking and dragging while holding down the centre mouse wheel button, or press and hold down the spacebar and move the mouse, Zoom in/out using  Ctrl+scroll wheel, or + or - keys.